# Fluent nHibernate - Query Cache not working with "session.Query" and Cacheable()

Tags: nhibernate, caching, fluent

Did't get any QueryCacheHitCount. The Source Code looks like:
nHibernate 3.3.1.4000, FluentnHibernate 1.3.0.733

Config:

```
Factory = Fluently.Configure()
    .ExposeConfiguration(c =>
        c.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.GenerateStatistics, "true"))
    .Database(
    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.Is("DATA SOURCE=localhost;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=AAA;Password=AAA"))
            .ShowSql()
    )
    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Localization.NHibernate.Article>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildDatabase)
    .Cache(
        x => x.UseSecondLevelCache()
                .UseQueryCache()                         
                .ProviderClass<NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider>())
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Execute:

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Factory.Statistics.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Article s = session.Query<Article>().Cacheable().Where(x => x.Name == "O").SingleOrDefault();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Factory.Statistics.QueryCacheHitCount);
    Console.WriteLine(Factory.Statistics.SecondLevelCacheHitCount);
    Console.WriteLine(Factory.Statistics.QueryExecutionCount);
}
```

---

Only if i change the cache config and add my private `QueryCacheFactory` with `.QueryCacheFactory<CacheFactory>()` than it works (But i ignore the `IsUpToDate` check)

```
public class CacheFactory : NHibernate.Cache.IQueryCacheFactory
{
    public NHibernate.Cache.IQueryCache GetQueryCache(string regionName, NHibernate.Cache.UpdateTimestampsCache updateTimestampsCache, Settings settings, IDictionary<string, string> props)
    {
        return new MyStandardQueryCache(settings, props, updateTimestampsCache, regionName);
    }

    private class MyStandardQueryCache : NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache
    {
        public MyStandardQueryCache(Settings settings, IDictionary<string, string> props, NHibernate.Cache.UpdateTimestampsCache updateTimestampsCache, string regionName)
            : base(settings, props, updateTimestampsCache, regionName) { }

        protected override bool IsUpToDate(Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<string> spaces, long timestamp)
        {
            return true; // SET TO TRUE than it's hitting the cache
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and from a I can remember, the results of the query are cached using the creation time of the session or the transaction. Try using a session for first query and different one for the following, doing that you should receive cache hits.